# Intuition behind Normal distribution forumula

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

In this formula

$$ P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{ - \frac{ \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 }{2\sigma^2}} $$

why do we divide by square root 2 pi and after that multiply everything by e in some power - how all these thing contribute to normal distribution individually?

Comment: The $\dfrac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}$ makes the integral over the real numbers equal to $1$ and so makes this a probability density

Comment: I have edited your LaTeX.  Please make shure it is what you intended

Answer (score 1):

Try twiddling with the sliders on [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/trgedt6niv) page.